# React-redux, nextauth, next.js error depreciation error

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-redux

So I am trying to add React-redux to my next.js app that also uses Next Auth. And seem to be unable to figure out how to get rid of the depreciation error.

my `_app.tsx`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' // Import bootstrap CSS
import { SessionProvider, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React from 'react'
import { wrapper } from "../store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { useStore } from "react-redux";

// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
import { Head } from 'next/document'

const BackgroundImage = dynamic(
    () => {
        return import('../components/BackgroundImage')
    },
    {
        ssr: false,
        loading: () => <p>...</p>,
    }
)

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, pageProps } }) {
    const store: any = useStore();
    return (
        <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
            <SessionProvider session={session}>
                {Component.auth ? (
                    <Auth>
                        <Head>
                            {/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-title-in-document-head */}
                            <title>Mobius Infernium | MC</title>
                            <meta
                                name="viewport"
                                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
                            ></meta>
                        </Head>
                        <NavBar />
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                        <BackgroundImage />
                    </Auth>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <NavBar />
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                        <BackgroundImage />
                    </>
                )}
            </SessionProvider>
        </PersistGate>
    )
}

function Auth({ children }) {
    // if `{ required: true }` is supplied, `status` can only be "loading" or "authenticated"
    const { status } = useSession({ required: true })

    if (status === 'loading') {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return children
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

Now I use a store file to create the wrapper which has been imported. so my error is in the app file. Any suggestions on how to fix this properly?

LOG:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\disda\Desktop\mobiusinferniummc.com\.env
event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.1s (647 modules)
wait  - compiling /404 (client and server)...
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1799 ms (666 modules)
redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.
The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` is deprecated, and will be removed in RTK 2.0. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice
/!\ You are using legacy implementation. Please update your code: use createWrapper() and wrapper.useWrappedStore().
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.
The object notation for `createSlice.extraReducers` is deprecated, and will be removed in RTK 2.0. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice
/!\ You are using legacy implementation. Please update your code: use createWrapper() and wrapper.useWrappedStore().
```